# Deserialize child elements with a certain name into a list

Tags: java, simple-framework

I'm loading an external XML similar to this:

```
<list>
    <item>test</item>
    <item>test</item>
    <item>test</item>
    <summary>3</summary>
</list>
```

How can I annotate a `private List<String> items;` field so that the Simple framework deserializes the three `item` tags but not the `summary` tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
@ElementList(inline = true, name = "item")
private List<String> items;
```